# Create a .xml file with same as .txt file after conversion using elementree python

Tags: python, xml

I am in a project in which I have the task to convert a text file to xml file.

But the restriction is, the file names should be same. I use element tree

module of python for this but while writing to the tree I use tree.write()

method in which I have to explicitly define / hardcode the xml filename

myself.

I want to know is there any procedure to automatically create the .xml file

with same name as the text file

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), also please state what problem you are having.

Answer (score -1):

the sh module provides great flexibility and may help you for what you want to do if I understand the question correctly. I have shown an example in the following:

```
import sh
name = "filename.xml"
new_name = name[-3] + "txt" 
sh.touch(new_name)
```

from there you can open the created file and write directly to it.